# Show that the gcd between two polynomials equals 1

Tags: real-analysis

Given the polynomial $P(x)=x^3-x-1$, I have shown that it has a real, irrational solution named $a$.

The problem asked is : if a polynomial $Q$, with coefficients in the field $\Bbb Q$, is of degree less or equal than $2$, then $\gcd(P,Q)=1$.

It's pretty obvious when the degree of $Q$ equals $0$ and $1$ but, knowing $P$ can be written as $P(x)=(x-a)R(x)$ with $R$ a polynomial of degree $2$, why can't $Q=R$?

I think that the constant term of $R$ must be $1/a$, an irrational number, for the constant term of the product of $(x-a)$ and $R$ to be equal to $1$. Therefore $R$ doesn't have its coefficients in the field $\Bbb Q$, therefore $R$ can't be equal to $Q$.

But I don't feel like it's a good answer.

Comment: Is there any non-trivial factors of $P(x)$ with rational coefficients? If no, since $\gcd(P, Q) \mid P$, and $\deg( \gcd(P,Q) \leq \deg (Q)$, this implies that $\gcd(P, Q) = 1$.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  The only problem with this analysis is that you haven't established that $x^3-x-1$ doesn't also have a rational solution in addition to $a$.  (It doesn't, but the work above doesn't show that.)  Another possibility is to use long division to show that there's a linear combination of $P(x)$ with an arbitrary quadratic polynomial that results in the polynomial $1$.

Comment: thank you very much for the editing, and for the answers!